# algorithm2e: too wide when in \item

Tags: lists, algorithm2e

Consider

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tworuled]{algorithm2e}%%% v5.1 or v5.2. Could not find v5.3 for download.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  TEST1
\end{algorithm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2]

  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    TEST2
  \end{algorithm}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  TEST3
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

In the output

[image: latex output]

the horizontal lines around TEST2 are too long. If we had more text in TEST2, it would also go beyond the right border into the margin. Is there a possibility to let TEST2 end at the right text border more-or-less automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `algorithm`s are meant to float where there aren't any restrictions in terms of the width (it's usually `\textwidth`). If you want to have the `algorithm`s inline (and not floating; by using the `[H]`ere float specifier), then you'll have to set it inside a `minipage` of pre-specified width - `\linewidth` in this case:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tworuled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  TEST1
\end{algorithm}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \lipsum[2]

  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    TEST2
  \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  TEST3
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```